# Axios JWT doesn't send

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, axios, jwt

I have a project divided in two layers. The back-end is developed in spring boot, secured by Sprint security and JWT, and the front-end is developed in Vue.js, using Axios library for communication between layers.

I receive the "Bearer token" authentication properly, and all the authentication process is done correctly. The issue appears when I try to send a request with a token header to access content but the token doesn't send, and the Spring boot returns null without the content.

Here is the code

```
getOffers: function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem("userSession")) {
      this.aux = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userSession"));
      this.token = this.aux.token;
      this.tokenHeader = "Bearer "+this.token;
      alert(this.tokenHeader)
    };
    console.log(`Bearer ${this.token}`)
    axios.
    get('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/offer', {'Authorization' : `Bearer ${this.token}`})
            .then(response => {
              console.log(response);
              this.offers = response.data
            }).catch(e => console.log(e))
  }
```

P.S: When I make a request in Postman, it works fine and returns the desired object. Here is a postman example:
[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ccex3.png)

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. Take a tour and get your first badge-https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct way to pass header is :

```js
axios.get(uri, { headers: { "header1": "value1", "header2": "value2" } })
```

In your case try this:

```js
axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/offer', { headers:{Authorization : `Bearer ${this.token}`} })
```

Also, check in console if this gives correct `Bearer` token:

```js
console.log(`Bearer ${this.token}`)
```

Comment: It still doesn't work.
I tried the 
`axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/offer', { headers:{Authorization : `Bearer ${this.token}`} })` but still don't send the token.
The console.log returns me `Bearer {token}`

Comment: what does it give?  - console.log(`Bearer ${this.token}`)

Comment: Specifically it returns this to me `Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJxd2VydHkiLCJleHAiOjE1ODkwNjIzNDEsImlhdCI6MTU4OTA0NDM0MX0.6S4V4XUB2sy2gzMx7Moh8yIcDlGQ8-xiuO8za6bkHHJim2H0tYGA268fULHMYO7pqipr3ikbK-ka-1k-ezXUAg`
I tried it in Postman and it works correctly

Comment: may be single quote is creating issue, try - `Authorization : this.tokenHeader` without any single quote.

Comment: `{ headers:{Authorization : this.tokenHeader}}` nothing yet.
[Test](https://imgur.com/a/nYsNCv5) in postman

Comment: Yes, It returns all the data I need

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/a/LqdQYtg) is what the console show me

Comment: Are [CORS](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework) are enabled in your security configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

Register the Bearer Token as a common header with Axios so that all outgoing HTTP requests automatically have it attached.

```
window.axios = require('axios')
let bearer = window.localStorage['auth_token']

if (bearer) {`enter code here`
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + bearer
}
```

And no need to send bearer token on every request.